# How to use python iterators in a pure functional workflow

Tags: python, functional-programming, semantics

Something that has been bothering me is that python iterators do not fall into the definition of a pure immutable object as re accessing them modifies their behavior.
I understand the way this works but reading code with iterators can become confusing and doesn't seem very pythonic.

My question is... is there a nice pythonic way to approach this?

I.e.  The use of an iterator here results in a side effect(input argument is modified) makes the function impure

```py
def foo(i):
    return list(i)
b = iter([1,2,3])
print(foo(b)) # outputs [1,2,3]
print(foo(b)) # outputs [] 
print(list(b)) # outputs []
```

Comment: You can make your own persistent generator, provided you are willing to lose features of the native type. FP utilizes corecursion to get iterator like behavior. In order for corecursion to work on infinite data structures lazyness is required though. I don't know how you can express that with python but in JS there are lazy object getters to the rescue. Here is a little JS sketch of an [persistent iterator based on corecursion](https://repl.it/@scriptum/CadetblueWarpedFan) which you might want to convert to python.

Answer (score 0):

Issue in your example is that your iterator `a` state is in global scope which sort of already clashes with "no side-effects" rule. Once it gets exhausted (eg, it has throw StopIteration exception), its done and has to be reinitialized.

```py
from copy import copy
def foo(i):
    return list(i)

a = [1,2,3]
b = iter(a)
print(foo(copy(b))) # outputs [1,2,3]
print(foo(copy(b))) # outputs [1,2,3]
print(list(copy(b))) # outputs [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting! I have updated the example code. ('a' inside the foo method should have been 'i')

Comment: your change does not change anything, you are passing the same iterator to both calls of `foo()`. Maybe i wasn't clear by pointing that once you create iterator, it will hold it's own state within itself. So, once the iterator is exhausted, it will not produce same results. Well, you could say that iterator is not pure in how you are using it.

Comment: This is mostly be design of iterator and/or because in this case, the iterator is passed "as a reference". In order to avoid this. See my added example that mimics yours..